# Binding a datepicker to dynamically generated textboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-4

I have several textbox elements being generated in a foreach, like this:

```
@foreach(var thing in Model.Things)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => thing.StartDate, new { id = "thingStartDate", @class = "thingDatePicker" })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I'm attaching jQuery datepickers to each textbox, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thingDatePicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });
});
```

The datepickers all fire correctly on each textbox, in the correct positions.  But when I select a date from any of them, it only populates the first textbox.  How do I make sure each datepicker is firmly associated with its textbox?

Comment: Are you giving your textbox a name attribute?

Comment: @MikeRobinson No, just the id and the class.  Do I need that?

Comment: I don't see anything in the code referencing name, however I've had similar experiences with other widgets and found it to be a good first test.

Comment: Can you post the outputted HTML rather than the asp.net source or an example on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the same id for all your textboxes (`id="thingStartDate"`) which obviously results in invalid HTML. So either remove the id attribute or make sure you don't get dupes. I would probably remove it as you are using a class selector and this id serves no purpose at all:

```
@foreach(var thing in Model.Things)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(
                m => thing.StartDate, 
                new { @class = "thingDatePicker" }
            )
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Also I hope you realize that `m => thing.StartDate` will generate incorrect names for those textboxes. It will use `name="StartDate"` instead of `name="Things[xxx].StartDate"` which might get you into troubles later when you attempt to bind back to your view model. For this purpose I recommend scraping the `foreach` loops in view in favor of editor/display templates:

```
@Html.editorFor(x => x.Things)
```

and inside the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Thing.cshtml`)

```
@model Thing
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(
            x => x.StartDate, 
            new { @class = "thingDatePicker" }
        )
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I need the id for some other stuff, so I switched to a `for` loop and constructed the id with the iterator, and now everything works great.  Thanks!